# PathBuf::starts_with doesn't work with backslashes

Tags: windows, rust

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let p = PathBuf::from(r"\\?\C:\test");
    println!("{}", p.starts_with(r"\\?\"));
    println!("{}", p.starts_with("r\\"));
    println!("{}", p.to_string_lossy().starts_with(r"\\?\"));
}
```

Results:

```
false
false
true
```

When I try the same with `/` instead of `\` then it works as expected. Why doesn't `starts_with` work with backslashes?

Comment: [I'm not sure PathBuf works well with UNC paths](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65397), you may want to do string munging by hand there.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine to test, but out of curiosity, what are the [components](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.components) of such a path?

Comment: components returns ```Some(Normal("\\\\?\\C:\\test"))```

Comment: I would try `p.starts_with(r"\\?\C:")`. I've never used Rust, but according to the docs [`starts_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.starts_with) "[o]nly considers whole path components to match". A fully-qualified Windows path has a [`PrefixComponent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PrefixComponent.html), for which one of the prefix types is `VerbatimDisk`, e.g. "\\?\C:".

Answer (score 1):

According to a reply on rust-lang.org forum: PathBuf API skips it for the path introspection API, such that `\\?\C:\path` behaves the same as `C:\path`.
answers the question. This behavior is annoying and should be explicitly mentioned in the docs.